# Finding mongodb elements by date range using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run a query by 3 values, one being a date range.
This is a snippet from my backend file that activates on a button press from the client side. The data is then sent back to the client for parsing and display in a graph.

```js
async function loadData(event, type, ta, startDate, endDate, amount) {
    startDate = new Date(startDate);
    endDate = new Date(endDate);
    //I run a query here using my model defined in the Schema
    const query = DigitalChartRecorder.find({
        Type: type,
        TA: ta,
        Date: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate}
    }).limit(amount);
    query.getFilter();
    let raw = await query.exec();
    //Check length of result
    console.log(raw.length);
    event.reply("load-5-r", JSON.stringify(raw));
}
ipcMain.on("load-5", loadData);
```

When querying without the date limit everything returns as expected, including the formatted DateTime from my mongoose model.

I'm not quite sure where I've gone wrong according to the other SO posts and [this doc post](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/dates.html#querying).

Edit:
Schema file:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const DCRSchema = new Schema({
    Type: String,
    Date: Date,
    TA: String,
    Data: {
        DateTime: Date,
        Temperature: Number,
        Humidity: Number,
        TemperatureSP: Number,
        HumiditySP: Number
    },
    Hash: {type: String},
    Time: {type: String, required: false},
}, { collection: "TestData" } );

const DigitalChartRecorder = mongoose.model('DigitalChartRecorder', DCRSchema);

export default DigitalChartRecorder;
```

Example document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cf7fb91ab374570a4ac8a9f"),
    "Type" : "Digital Chart Recorder",
    "Date" : "6/5/2019 1:27:34 PM",
    "TA" : "F-3233",
    "Data" : "[{\"DateTime\":\"06/05/2019 13:27:05.9\",\"Temperature\":\"0.13\",\"Humidity\":\"34.04\"}]",
    "Hash" : "45624e408cc0e552470198a7882b9e2f0e7adc18f134d0c6a09f38a746a701237a0874a71b485d8b342bd445f638e9f30f5c7a61bfea4b5e26c766f3be103ca7"
}
```

Database.js

```js
const database = require('mongoose');

const connString = "mongodb://truncated for security";

export function connectDev(){
    database.connect(connString, {dbName: "DEVDB", useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
    const db = database.connection;
    db.on('error', (e)=>{
        console.error(e);
    });
    db.once('open', function() {
        console.info("Connected");
    });
}

export function connectProd(){
    connectDev();
}

export default { database }
```

Mongoose query being run:

```
←[0;36mMongoose:←[0m TestData.find({ Type: ←[32m'Digital Chart Recorder'←[39m, TA: ←[32m'F-3233'←[39m, Date: { ←[32m'$gte'←[39m: new Date("Wed, 05 Jun 2019 04:00:00 GMT"), ←[32m'$lte'←[39m: new Date("Sun, 09 Jun 2019 04:00:00 GMT") }}, { limit: ←[33m10000←[39m, projection: {} })
```

Comment: Based on your post, you are storing the date as a string.  Rather than store the date as a string, store it as a date.  In MongoDB you can see the date datatype easily by querying with mongo shell.  It will show the date as ISODate("2019-06-05T13:27:34.123Z").  Please keep in mind, storing dates in Mongo will be in UTC datetime.  Drivers can be used to augment to localization time zones.

Comment: @barrypicker I've made a datetime query like this to the same database in python, using a US date string format and it worked, so I don't understand why a date object, or string query, doesn't work here. Mongoose is supposed to cast dates automatically as well.

Comment: To compare, both the field type and the input parameter data types must be the same.

Comment: @JakeStarr - if Mongoose is supposed to cast dates automatically then there is no need to describe the date string format as that is an irrelevant concept when performing a date range query.  You could trace the database using db.setProfilingLevel(2) to see what query is actually submitted.  You might be surprised to find what mongoose is actually submitting.  At any rate, you have only provided a node snippet.  It would be helpful if you included a complete working code file and an example of the documents you are attempting to query.

Comment: @barrypicker I updated the original post to include more code from the project. As well as the query being run by mongoose.

Comment: well, like I said you would be surprised by what mongoose is submitting as the query.  Here you are querying for a field called "Date" with a date operator but the data in the database is not a date, its a string.  Like I said earlier, if you store the dates as strings you will have problems.  You would be better suited to store the date as a date.

Comment: @barrypicker I updated the previous string data to a date object in mongo, and querying by date is working now. I just want to confirm that this is the way its supposed to look. https://pastebin.com/RQiQAT0W